# Speaker connected via AUX port doesn't work with my Ubuntu notebook (but does on other devices)

Tags: sound

I have an aux speaker, and when I plug it into my notebook running Ubuntu it won't work at all, although it works fine with other machines. My internal speaker works too, but I can't seem to make this speaker work with this system.

Comment: solved I just disabled "independent hp" option in alsamixer menu!

Answer (score 3):

[Copied from Question owner's comments from the question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1009819/having-trouble-with-aux-port#comment1635715_1009819):

> Solved. I just disabled "independent hp" option in alsamixer menu!